# Changing the date format for MySQL within a p4a field

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am using the p4a application framework and I have build several databases one of which needs to gather the date of a booking, I understand that there Isn't a way to do this through MySQL but I haven't found anything useful on the p4a forums on this so anyone that uses the p4a framework that could help, I would be grateful,

I have my local set as `en_GB` which sets the date within the p4a field as `dd-mm-yyyy` but I need it to be `yyyy-mm-dd` to actually write the data into the database,

the present code for this operation is:

```
$this->build("p4a_field","date")
         ->setlabel("Date")
         ->setType('date')
```

---

```
$location = $this->AreaName->getNewValue();
    $date = $this->date->getNewValue();
    $merono = $this->merono->getNewValue();

    $p4a = p4a::singleton();


$p4a->i18n->autoUnformat($date, "shortdate");

    p4a_db::singleton()->query("INSERT INTO meetingrooms(location, date, merono)
        VALUES
        ('$location', '$date', '$merono')");
```

Any help would be appreciated, I was planning on intercepting the function using `afterClick` but I need to know the syntax required first.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have some dates in a non-MySQL-friendly format, but you want to use them for `INSERTs`, right?

How about letting MySQL [convert them for you](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)?

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('31-12-2012','%d-%m-%Y');
    -> '2012-12-31'
```

EDITS:

It looks like you have the date:

```
$date = $this->date->getNewValue();
```

so you need to use the formula in your SQL:

```
p4a_db::singleton()->query("INSERT INTO meetingrooms(location, date, merono)
VALUES
('$location', STR_TO_DATE('$date','%d-%m-%Y'), '$merono')");
```

I'm not a p4a guy, so hopefully that'll work.

Note that, in most languages, you'll be exposed to SQL injection with code like that.  Does p4a cover that for you, or provide for positional parameters?

Good luck.

Comment: I'm not sure how i would implement this into my document, could you lend a hand on that front?